# Laravel: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the following error on my laravel backend:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

It's happening on the following method

```php
$matchedUsers = User::whereHas('matches', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_liked_id', 1)->orWhere('user_matched_id', 1);
})->doesntHave('chats', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', 1)->orWhere('receiver_id', 1);
})->get();
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Sorry, scratch my last comment; it was half-correct. I think you just need to use `->whereDoesntHave()` instead of `->doesntHave()`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence. `->doesntHave()` only takes 1 argument, not 2.

Comment: it's whereDoesntHave, doesnthave only get the relation name